# File download variants on sharepoint, is this possible

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible on Sharepoint to make such a repository so when user would click on a file, somewhat menu /option would show up, so he could choose the file extension to download? That what you could upload file once, with it's preview thumbnail visible, and it could be downloaded in a form user chooses to, instead of uploading and displaying every extension

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible out-of-the-box. You could create an SPFx ListView Command Set to show custom options when they click the ellipsis next to a file but SharePoint only stores the file as one type. It does allow you to convert a file to PDF natively, so you could create an option that uses the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to do that.

Comment: All of the extensions which would be allow to download, will be uploaded by me. I just don't want them all visible because of the clutter. I don't want sharepoint to convert anything, I just want, after choosing specific extension, to connect to it, and start downloading

Comment: The issue is that these are separate files and are treated as such when they are uploaded to a document library.